# preselect select field with freemarker

Tags: forms, struts2, freemarker

In my struts2 action that prepares the ftl page i have

```
private static List<Product> listOfProducts;
```

with getter and setters. This list is filled with products. First product in the list has type B.

In ftl page I am iterating over the list of products

```
<#list listOfProducts as product>
<select name = product[0].type>
  <option value="A">fistType</option>
  <option value="B">secondType</option>
  <option value="C">thirdType</option>
</select>
</#list>
```

Problem is that firstType is preselected each time even if in the list i have a product with type B.

Can you tell me what am i missing  here? Why option B was not selected when the ftl is loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp on the correct syntax for a select

The attribute "name" sets the name of the control - it does not influence the selection

See [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element)
on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use Struts select tag.

```
<@s.select theme="simple" name="selectedProduct" list="listOfProducts" listKey="productId" listValue="productName" value="defaultProduct"/>
```

Please go through the example in below link for more understanding.

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/