# How to set default value to select tag dynamically?

Tags: html, dynamic, html-select

I am trying to add a default value to the options in the select tag.

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I was wondering if you could set the default value as the value that the user chose.
For example, if the user chose 2 and submitted the form, how can I set the default value to 2?

Comment: You would have to set a cookie storing their selection and then auto-select that option when they return.

Comment: refer [http://www.w3schools.com/](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp)

Comment: The value selected by the user will remain selected, so what is the point? If you mean that the value should be the default if the user later visits the page, please clarify it in the question. (Then you would need to use cookies or `localStorage`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set default value for HTML select element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element)

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute "checked" to the option you want as the default. Something along the lines of...

`<option>1</option>
<option <?php echo $_POST["select_name"] == 2 ? "checked": ""; ?> >2</option><option>3</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea @Bollis

But i am not sure `checked` is the correct attribute now. Its changed to `selected` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#selected))

So for my usecase with `html + php` I used got it working like this -
First I have a `php` variable that determines the default-dropdown value that I have to show on the page -

```php
<?php
    $default_value = 2;
?>
```

Then in my `html` `<select>`, I did this -

```html
<select name="selectionName" id="selectionId">
    <option 
        <?php 
            echo $default_value == "" ? "selected" : ""; 
        ?>  
        value= "">None</option>
    <option <?php echo $default_value == "1" ? "selected" : ""; ?> value="1">1</option>
    <option <?php echo $default_value == "2" ? "selected" : ""; ?>  value="2">2</option>
    <option <?php echo $default_value == "3" ? "selected" : ""; ?>  value="3">3</option>
    <option <?php echo $default_value == "4" ? "selected" : ""; ?>  value="4">4</option>
    <option <?php echo $default_value == "5" ? "selected" : ""; ?>  value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

***Explanation***: In each `<option>`, the `$deafult_value` variable is checked and **if its value is the same as to value** of that `<option>`, then the `selected` attribute is `echo`ed out.
This enabled that `<option>` to be dynamically selected based on the value of the `$default_value` variable.