# PHP Selection List - Default value shoud be "all" (or "Alle")

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, list, dom

I have a website that shows users data based on the State they live in. There is a filter via a drop-down list that allows them to select any State or all States. **The current default selection is to show them the data from THEIR State.**

**I want to change the default to show all States** (**no filter**). There is a list item at the top called "Alle" that does this, but I don't know how to make this the default when the webpage loads.

**Here's the current code:**

```
<label class="control-label" for="Bundesland">Bundesland:</label>
<div class="controls">
    <select class="span12" id="Bundesland" name="filter[bundesland]">
        <option value="">Alle</option>
                        <?php
                            $a = [
                            '01' => 'Schleswig-Holstein',
                            '02' => 'Hamburg',
                            '03' => 'Niedersachsen',
                            '04' => 'Bremen',
                            '05' => 'Nordrhein-Westfalen',
                            '06' => 'Hessen',
                            '07' => 'Rheinland-Pfalz',
                            '08' => 'Baden-Württemberg',
                            '09' => 'Bayern',
                            '10' => 'Saarland',
                            '11' => 'Berlin',
                            '12' => 'Brandenburg',
                            '13' => 'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern',
                            '14' => 'Sachsen',
                            '15' => 'Sachsen-Anhalt',
                            '16' => 'Thüringen',
                            ];
                            asort($a);
                        ?>
                        <?php foreach ($a as $code=>$name): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$code?>" <?=$code == $this->filter['bundesland'] ? 'selected' : ''?>><?=$name?></option>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
```

**Screenshot of drop-down list:**

[image: Screenshot of drop-down list]

Comment: What happened to all the comments? We were so close to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

HTML's element:  has an attribute; 'selected'. At the page load, make the first one 'selected'. Read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

```
 <option value="" selected>Bitte wählen</option>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The solution might require AJAX. Desired result: on page load: Filter = "Alle". I only know some CSS and zero Javascript. Could someone please kindly provide the needed code?

Comment: So, at the load of the page you want to filter it directly?

Comment: At the load of the page, it should show the results for **all** German states. It should show the same results as when I manually select "Alle" from the dropdown list. I don't know if that is a "filter" or "no filter". :-\

Comment: It's likely that the default filter is set by (or read from) the database and/or the user's profile. I want to override that setting using the code above (until I have many more users).

Comment: Your answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element

Comment: That would be the answer if the **PHP code** weren't there. Somehow, the `selected` in the PHP code **might** need to be removed and perhaps somehow added to the `<option value="">Alle</option>`. I think the `value` parameter there might be relevant too (for the PHP selection).

Comment: Is there something I can do to increase the likelihood that someone will answer this question?