# Default Value in a select

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, pdo

This is for a PHP application using PDO for the database binding.  I'm working on an edit form and what I have so far works perfectly except for the drop down menu.  I can't seem to get it to show the current value of the device I'm editing.  It only shows a blank line.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<select name='connectedTerminal' id='connectedTerminal'>
<option value='0'>Select Terminal</option>
<option value='$row[connectedTerminal]' selected='selected' text='$row[connectedTerminal]'></option>
$options_terminal;
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set default value for HTML select element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if condition

```
<select name='connectedTerminal' id='connectedTerminal'>
<option value='0'>Select Terminal</option>
<option <?php if($row[connectedTerminal] == '1') echo "selected " ?> value='1'>$row[connectedTerminal]</option>
<option <?php if($row[connectedTerminal] == '2') echo "selected " ?> value='2'>$row[connectedTerminal]</option>
$options_terminal; // what it is for?
</select>
```

Comment: The $options_terminal is the list pulled from the database of possible options.

Comment: @JohnHaag is my answer works for you? Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Yes it did.  I voted your answer up.  Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The text to display for a select element goes inbetween the `<option>` tags, the same as you already have for "Select Terminal"

```
<select name='connectedTerminal' id='connectedTerminal'>
<option value='0'>Select Terminal</option>
<option value='$row[connectedTerminal]' selected='selected'>$row[connectedTerminal]</option>
$options_terminal;
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set default value use [`selected="selected"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element)

```
<select name='connectedTerminal' id='connectedTerminal'>
  <option selected="selected" value='0'>Select Terminal</option> 
  <option value="<?php echo $row[connectedTerminal]; ?>"><?php echo $row[connectedTerminal];?></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name='connectedTerminal' id='connectedTerminal'>
<option value='0'>Select Terminal</option>
<option value='<?php echo $row[connectedTerminal] ;?>' selected='selected' text='<?php echo $row[connectedTerminal];?>'><?php echo $options_terminal; ?></option>
</select>
```

You are trying to out put PHP variable inside html.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an array of terminals

```
$terminals = array();
$terminals[1] = 'one';
$terminals[2] = 'two';
$terminals[3] = 'three';
$terminals[4] = 'four';
$terminals[5] = 'five';
```

And you are currently modifying record with `terminal` id `4` and the variable is `$terminal_id`

```
<select name='connectedTerminal' id='connectedTerminal'>
<option value='0'>Select Terminal</option>
<?php
if (! empty($terminals)) {
  foreach ($terminals as $tid => $tval) {
    $selected = ($tid == $terminal_id) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
?>
<option value="<?php echo $tid;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $tval;?></option>
<?php
  }
}
</select>
```