# Default value before change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple drop down list with values. On change, the value is passed to a variable `place`

The `place` value is passed to a div, which loads data from an api. It works fines after I select one of the values, but my initial value is blank.

How can I store a default value before the select list is clicked?

```
<select name="places">
  <option value="135264023">New York</option>
  <option value="116721348">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="104279908">Dubai</option>
</select>

<div id="widget"></div>

<script>
$('select').change(function() {
  var place = $(this).val();
  console.log(place);
  // This call have to happen after div and <script> tag.
  widgetOptions({
    element: 'widget',
    placeId: place,
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `<option value="135264023" selected>New York</option>` or `document.querySelector('[name="places"]').selectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an option to be the default by adding the `selected` boolean attribute to it, but my guess is that your real question is how to trigger loading the information at the outset.

Add the `selected` (although it's very likely to have already defaulted to the first one):

```
<select name="places">
  <option value="135264023" selected>New York</option><!-- Note change -->
  <option value="116721348">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="104279908">Dubai</option>
</select>
```

...and then in your script:

```
var sel = $("select"); // You probably want this to be more specific
setupPlace(sel.val());
sel.change(function() {
  setupPlace($(this).val());
});
function setupPlace(place) {
  console.log(place);
  // This call have to happen after div and <script> tag.
  widgetOptions({
    element: 'widget',
    placeId: place,
  });
}
```

Note how we've isolated the logic into a function, and then we call that function from the two places we need it: Initialization, and change.

Alternately, you see people doing this kind of thing (still with that `selected` attribute):

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var place = $(this).val();
  console.log(place);
  // This call have to happen after div and <script> tag.
  widgetOptions({
    element: 'widget',
    placeId: place,
  });
}).trigger("change"); // <== Only change is here
```

I'm not a fan of using a fake event to trigger a handler, but I can see the allure. It's largely a style choice.

Comment: You read my mind, my question was a bit vage. I was looking for how to trigger the first value without clicking. This worked like a charm!

Comment: I really like the information provided in your answer :) +1

Answer (score -1):

```js
var place = null;
$('select').click(function() {
 if(place === null) {
  place = $(this).val();  
 }
});

$('select').change(function() {
  //place = $(this).val();
  console.log(place);
  // This call have to happen after div and <script> tag.
  widgetOptions({
    element: 'widget',
    placeId: place,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="places">
  <option value="135264023">New York</option>
  <option value="116721348">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="104279908">Dubai</option>
</select>

<div id="widget"></div>
```