# Default text in dropdownlist jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery to generate a dynamic drop-down list. How can I set the default text in it(Ex: Select a city)? Thanks!

Here is the script:

```
var ss = $('#ss');
var select = $('<select></select>').attr({ id: name, name: name });

$.each(u.Options, function (i, option) {
   select.append($('<option</option>').val(option.Value).text(option.Text));
})
ss.append(select);
```

Comment: note typo in `'<option</option>'`... can change to `'<option>'` will work the same

Comment: Here is a relevant answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a first `option` before the `$.each` loop to set the default choice:

```
var $ss = $('#ss');
var $select = $('<select />', { id: name, name: name });    
$('<option />', { text: 'Select a city', value: '' }).appendTo($select);

$.each(u.Options, function (i, option) {
    $('<option />', { text: option.Text, value: option.Value }).appendTo($select);
})
$ss.append($select);
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend an option somewhere ?

```
select.prepend('<option>Select a city</option>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ptwusyq1/)