# Set default value on select drop down in HTML?

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to set the default value for a select drop down, but for some reason the below (which is the only recommended solution I could find) doesn't seem to work:

```
<div>
   <div class="label">Car hire</div>
   <select class="custom-dropdown" ng-model="quote.user.carHire">
      <option>Standard - 30 days</option>
      <option>Standard - 60 days</option>
      <option>Executive - 30 days</option>
      <option>Executive - 30 days</option>
      <option selected="selected">None</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try <option selected>None</option>

Comment: Also, please include the browser and browser version. Are you using any JavaScript library?

Comment: This is an online [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/cekuvakuza/edit?html,output) of your code and it is working fine using Google Chrome version 47

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: `selected` property in the `<option>` is the only way to make it. Maybe you have another code that conflicts.

Comment: Maybe angular is messing up the markup selection based on the model (`ng-model="quote.user.carHire"`)?