# How to make input selected after the refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to display form inputs without loosing data entered before refresh the page? I mean After refresh my page I want to display all the values entered in forms.

I have 2 inputs One is select option and one is text.

```
 <input type="text" name="worked_month" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['worked_month']; ?>" />
 <select name="sex">
     <option value="">Select Sex</option>
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
 </select>
```

I am using following PHP code to display text enter before I refresh the page

```
isset($_POST['worked_month'])?$_SESSION['worked_month'] = $_POST['worked_month']:$_SESSION['worked_month']="";
```

It works fine but don't know how to select the option that are selected before refresh. But I don't have to always select same default value. User can select any value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: Did you consider `local storage`?

Comment: @LionelChan sorry its far away from my query

Comment: @john no, i have no idea what to do.And I knw If i have to select default value `selected="selected"` can be used, but user can select any option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select option you have to use PHP dynamic variable.[Check this reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
<?php
$sex = $_SESSION['sex'];

${$sex.'_checked'} = "selected";

?>

<select name="sex">
<option value="">Select Sex</option><option value="male" <?php echo $male_checked; ?> >Male</option><option value="female" <?php echo $female_checked; ?>>Female</option></select>
```

Dynamic variable: automatic convert your selected value into variable whose value is "selected".

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation**. For each option, check if the post variable matches the value and then use **selected** attribute to select the matched option.

```
<select name="sex">
  <option value="">Select Sex</option>
  <option <?php echo isset($_POST['sex']) && $_POST['sex']=='male'? 'selected="selected"' = '' ?> value="male">Male</option>
  <option <?php echo isset($_POST['sex']) && $_POST['sex']=='female'? 'selected="selected"' = '' ?> value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "do it like this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thnx for pointing it out. added an explanation.

Comment: This works only if the action is done in the same file.. otherwise there should be used sessions..

Answer (score 0):

I just made something like that saving the values at Local Storage and then retrieving them:

```
//Saving the input values at local storage
var temp = [];
$('.keep-values').each(function(){
    temp.push({
      id:$(this).attr('id'),
      value:$(this).val().trim(),
      checked:$(this).is(':checked')
    });
});
localStorage['valuesCache'] = JSON.stringify(temp);
```

Then i retrive the values and i populate the fields:

```
//Retrieving the values from local Storage and populating the inputs
var tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage['valuesCache']);
for(i in tmp) {
  $('#'+tmp[i].id).val(tmp[i].value);
  if(tmp[i].checked){
    $('#'+tmp[i].id).attr('checked','');
  }
}
```

I think thats a good start for your final solution, read more about [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)