# set default select values from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a default select value from the drop down where the data is dynamically generated.

```
<html>
<tr><td><Select id="charge" name="charge"/></td></tr>
</html>
```

I had used so ajax call to get the data and populated the list in to the id:charge.
Now from the list i need to keep one values as a default select .
Can any one help me .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('[name=charge]').val( 'Funds' );

});
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Set the `value` after appending `options` because when you are setting the `value`, there is no option in the select input to be selected...

Comment: you have to write `$('[name=charge]').val( 'Funds' );` within ajax success handler where data is getting attached to select box.

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: `select` requires closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('[name=charge]').append("<option selected>Funds</option>")

})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <Select id="charge" name="charge"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('[name=charge]').append("<option selected>Funds</option>")

    })
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#charge').append('<option value="funds">option1</option>');

});
```

*the use ajax data to append to same id*

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[name=charge]').append("<option>Funds1</option>");
$('[name=charge]').append("<option selected='selected'>Funds</option>");
$('[name=charge]').append("<option>Funds2</option>");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
  <tr><td><Select id="charge" name="charge"/>
        </td></tr>
```