# jQuery call bind after page load

Tags: jquery

I have got a form with two inputs *(there is a PHP script behind it)*:

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text1" disabled="disabled" />
```

The PHP script look into a database and mark "One" or "Two" with the `selected="selected"` attribute.

If "One" is selected, I want to activate the disabled text field. If any other entry is selected (in this example "Two"), the text field should be disabled. I wrote this jQuery code:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $("#select1").bind('change paste keyup', function() {
    if (this.value == 'One') {
      $("#text1").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#text1").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
</script>
```

My Problem:
When I visit the page and "One" is preselected, the text field is disabled. I must select "Two" and "One" again. After this, the text field is enabled. I want to check on page load which item is selected. I tried a lot with triggering a change like this, but it did not run:

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  $("#select1").trigger('change paste keyup');
});
```

I know I could use thinks like `.on` or `.change`, but I want to do it with `.bind`.

How can I call `.bind` on page load?

Comment: Are you looking for `default selected item`? If right, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: ps:     `if (this.value == 'One') {
      $("#text1").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#text1").prop('disabled', true);
    }`  =>     
      `$("#text1").prop('disabled', (this.value != 'One'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trigger the event on pageload

```
$("#select1").on('change', function() {
    $("#text1").prop('disabled', this.value !== 'One');
}).trigger('change');
```

- `bind` has been superseded by `on`, and shouldn't be used
- a select shouldn't have any key events, and can't be pasted to?
- you can use the condition direcly to set the property

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/m7mptjuc/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But can you tell me, why I shouldn't use bind?

Comment: Because it's superseded by `on`. There's no other reason than that for now, jQuery hasn't removed `bind`, they just recommend using `on`. Internally they do the same thing, for now!

Comment: After I add `$(function () { YOUR CODE });`, it worked like a charm, thanks!