# Displaying Default Value In Dropdown Based On Information From Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my edit page. I want the default value to be the time received from the database called @l.begginingTime, which will the same as one of the values in the dropdown.

How do I do this?

```
@foreach (var l in Model.Cleaner.TimeAvailables)
  {     
    <select class="form-control dropDown"  name="Sunday1From" value="@l.BegginingTime">
        <option value="">Unavailable</option>
        <option value="00:00:00">12:00 AM</option>
        <option value="00:30:00">12:30 AM</option>
        <option value="01:00:00">1:00 AM</option>
        <option value="01:30:00">1:30 AM</option>
        <option value="02:00:00">2:00 AM</option>
        <option value="02:30:00">2:30 AM</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: why are you putting the select in a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your dynamic value as an option then set the **selected** attribute

```
@foreach (var l in Model.Cleaner.TimeAvailables)
      {     
        <select class="form-control dropDown"  name="Sunday1From">
            <option value="@l.BegginingTime" selected>@l.BegginingTime</option>
            <option value="00:00:00">12:00 AM</option>
            <option value="00:30:00">12:30 AM</option>
            <option value="01:00:00">1:00 AM</option>
            <option value="01:30:00">1:30 AM</option>
            <option value="02:00:00">2:00 AM</option>
            <option value="02:30:00">2:30 AM</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the attribute `selected`. Add that to whichever option in the dropdown you want to be selected by default.

Reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element) for a similar question.

Comment: But it's not always the same? For each user it is a different time?

Comment: Sure, well it doesn't look like your options are dynamic right now. If you wanted a dynamic option to hold the value of the variable then try something like this

Comment: <option value="@l.BegginingTime" selected>@l.BegginingTime</option>

Comment: hmm this seems like the easiest. But I need to display it as Am/PM But when I try to change it to Datetime in order to display it as such I am getting an error. Any idea why this wouldn't work? @string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", new DateTime().Add(l.BegginingTime)) Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Add(System.TimeSpan)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery and javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropDown').val(beginTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a html select which is completely separate from your model. So there is two option here.

Create your dropdown with MVC like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Model.Cleaner.TimeAvailables", (SelectList)@l.BegginingTime)
```