# How to keep a particular value selected in select tag

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

Below is my drop down in JSP where in I have to show the year values and these year values are populated when the document is ready, for which I have written JavaScript code.

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Select Year ::</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id='getYear' onchange="yearChanged(this.value);">

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
```

and the corresponding javascript code that populates the values in it is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    var select = document.getElementById("getYear");

    for(var i=0 ; i < 8; i++){

        var displayPast10Year = (parseInt(year)) - i;
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = displayPast10Year;  
        select.add(option, 0);

     }


    select.valueOf(year);
    $("#getYear").val(year); 
    yearChanged(year);

});
```

My requirement is that the drop down (i.e select tag) shows the year value as 2016 when the document is ready. How do I do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it to 2017 when you do `$("#getYear").val(year);`.
If you want it set to 2016, you can either remove that line and add

```
if (displayPast10Year === 2016) {
  option.selected = 'selected';
}
```

in your `for` loop, or you can simply replace it with `$("#getYear").val(2016)`.

Now if you need it to always be `current year - 1`, replace 2016 with `year - 1` in either one of the above solutions.

Comment: No this still displays the last populated value (i.e current year - 2017)

Comment: Probably because you change it again later. Check my solution on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/svoc3q7e/
It works fine.

Comment: I tried copying exactly your code but don't know why its still not working.