# How can maintain as selected the second option in a drop down with random values?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to always maintain how to select the second option for its drop downs. The point here is that the value is random:

`MyBrowser.document.getElementById("multipleCat_1").Value = "RANDOMVALUE"`

How do I select the second option in a drop down menu?

HTML:

```
<select id="multipleCat_1">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="RANDOMVALUE">Second Option"</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: @bureaquete, I do not have access to the HTML code as I am only trying to access the website as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectedIndex` as below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#multipleCat_1 > option')[1].value = 'Got you!';

document.getElementById('multipleCat_1').selectedIndex = 1 

console.log(document.getElementById('multipleCat_1').value)
```

```html
<select id="multipleCat_1">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="RANDOMVALUE">Second Option"</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This code solved my problem `MyBrowser.document.getElementById("multipleCat_1").selectedIndex = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="multipleCat_1">
    <option value="A">AAA</option>
    <option value="B">BBB</option>
    <option value="C">CCC</option>
</select>

var options = document.querySelectorAll('#multipleCat_1 > option');
document.getElementById('multipleCat_1').value = options[1].value;
```