# Retaining selected option from dropdown

Tags: html, angular

i have a dropdown with different options. i want to keep the selected option at the top of the dropdown till the user changes it. Right now if i select any options and i go out of the component and then come back, the dropdown reset with the first value....

**HTML**

```
 <select class="form-control-mb-12"
                (change)="intSelection($event.target.value)" >

                    <option  value="1/4">1/4</option>
                    <option value="1/8">1/8</option>
                    <option  value="1/16">1/16</option>
                    <option  value="1/32">1/32</option>
 </select>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModuladorService } from 'app/Services/modulador.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-resumen',
  templateUrl: './resumen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resumen.component.scss'],
  providers: [ModuladorService]
})
export class ResumenComponent implements OnInit {

  intSelected : string = "" ;

  constructor(private _moduladorService:ModuladorService) {

        this.intSelected = this._moduladorService.obtenerParametros();

   }




  ngOnInit() {

  }

  intSelection(value){

    switch(value) {
    case "1/4":   
     this.intSelected = value;
       break;
    case "1/8":
     this.intSelected = value;           
       break;
    case "1/16":
     this.intSelected = value;
       break;
    case "1/32":
     this.intSelected = value;
       break;
  }
      this._moduladorService.actualizarParametros(this.intSelected);
  }
```

**SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InitParam } from 'app/layout/modulador/resumen/init-param'

@Injectable()
export class ModuladorService extends InitParam {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.load();
   }

   obtenerParametros(){

      var intSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('intSelected'));
      return intSelected;

   }

   actualizarParametros(newParam : any){

          var intSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('intSelected'));

          intSelected = newParam;

          localStorage.setItem('intSelected', JSON.stringify(intSelected));


   }

}
```

**iNIT FOR SERVICE**

```
export class InitParam {



load(){

        if(localStorage.getItem('intSelected')=== null ){
            console.log('No se encontraron parametros...');

            var intSelected = '1/4'

            localStorage.setItem('intSelected', JSON.stringify(intSelected));
        }else{
                console.log('Cargando parametros...');
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: you really don't need that switch statement there, it does nothing, just leave ```intSelection(value){ this.intSelected = value; }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the selected things in an `@Injectable` service, which, if not made as, definitely feels like, a singleton.

Or input / output it from / to a parent component.

Comment: can u give an example? im using service to storage data.. but dont know how to relate the storaged data with the dropwdown view. check now with full code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: not answering my question..... the users is the one who chose from the dropdown. and the the option he select is the one that should keep showing the dropwdown on the top .

Comment: This worked for me <select value="B">
  <option value="A">Apple</option>
  <option value="B">Banana</option>
  <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
</select>

Comment: 1. user selects something. 2. you save it in the service and put it at the top. 3. component is changed and returned back. 4. if something is saved in the service add it to the top again.

Comment: Also, don't hardcode the selections in the template, make an array ```options = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']``` then iterate them with ```ngFor``` like in the examples here - https://johnpapa.net/angular-2-ngfor/

Answer (score 0):

You need storage data in services. Services injectable to module. 
If you need save information in all application - use services in providers at app.module.ts

Comment: yes im doing that. but how do i keep the option selected in the dropdown. check now with full code.