# Setting angularJS select default value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I seem to have trouble setting a default value for a select dropdown with AngularJS. I have read similiar topics on StackOverflow, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me, so I decided to finally ask you guys :)

Bascically I want to implement an entry editing functionality in my app. So, the user clicks on the edit button, a modal pops up with a form with values filled from the object that was passed to the modal controller. I mean all of the values, but the "category" which I want to be presented as a dropdown select.

I think it's going to be easier to show in code, so I prepared this fiddle:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.dataReceived = {
    category: "FOOD"
  }

  $scope.availableCategories = {
    FOOD: "Food and drinks",
    FREE_TIME: "Free time",
    HOUSING: "Housing costs"
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select-category">Select category:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="select-category" ng-model="dataReceived.category" required>
    <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in availableCategories" ng-value="key">
      {{value}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>
```

I tried different ways of fixing it, but none have worked so far so please help! All I want to do is for the dropdown to say "Food and drinks" by default if passed object's category is "FOOD".
Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to use ng-options with key value pairs instead.

Like this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.dataReceived = {
    category: "FOOD"
  }

  $scope.availableCategories = {
    FOOD: "Food and drinks",
    FREE_TIME: "Free time",
    HOUSING: "Housing costs"
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select-category">Select category:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="select-category" ng-model="dataReceived.category" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in availableCategories " required>
  </select>
</div>

</div>
```

Hope it helps.