# Select default selected value in select tag in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

here is my code

```
<select class="form-control input-transparent" id="select-field" name="address" ngModel required>
     <optgroup *ngFor="let wallet of wallets" label="{{wallet.label}}">
         <option value="{{ wallet.address }}" [selected]="wallet.address == wallets[0].address">{{ wallet.address }}</option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to select first option as selected but still on default value was selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selected` is not supported with `ngModel`

You can use this sample code.
I have created a demo on **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zszsck?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**. I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> HTML Code

```
<select class="form-control input-transparent" id="select-field" name="address" required [(ngModel)]="address">
    <optgroup *ngFor="let wallet of wallets;" label="{{wallet.label}}">
        <option [value]="wallet.id">{{ wallet.address }}</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

> .ts Code

```
    address:number=1;
    wallets= [{
        id: 1,
        address: 'address1',
        label: 'Label 1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        address: 'address 2',
        label: 'Label 2'
   }]
```

Comment: thanks man ! working fine . whatever you are binding to [value] , you should set the value of the ngModel variable as one of its value . example if you are doing like this <option [value]="wallet.address ">{{ wallet.address }}</option> , then you can do in the component as address:string='address1';

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<selected>` tags property `value` and set it to your desired value.

```
<select value="wallets[0].address">
```

> You can set a pre-selected option in a drop-down list by using the value attribute for the  tag, i.e. , but it's not valid in the W3C validator. – Apostle May 20 '15 at 15:40
>   [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element#comment48800926_26868770)