# Need advice with html tag

Tags: html, function

Need some help, trying to make the "Choose your Installments plant" text as selected so is the default text that my customers will see before choosing from a dropdown the number of installments.

```
html = "<p><select class=\'installments-box\'><option value=\'-1\'>Choose your Installments plan</option>";
```

Comment: Set the option value to an empty string.

Comment: Add the [`selected` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes)?

Comment: You're also missing the closing `</select></p>`

Comment: @Brandon Presumably, more `<option>`s are added after that line before the `<select>` and `<p>` are closed.

Comment: @Xufox Correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selected` attribute on the `<option>` that you want to be selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to set the `selected` attribute to make a `select` tag display the first option by default.

Simply omit the `value` attribute from the first option, or set it to an empty string and the select will display the first option as selected.

Pen: https://codepen.io/alsoicode/pen/jpPxgx