# Set a default value on dropdown list <select> from the value in a table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to set default value in a  list box from the values in the table. The values are getting populated in the  listbox from the database and the values in the table are hard coded.
Can anybody help me with this?

```
<table>
  <td align="center">
  <a href="#" onclick="setExperienceValue("experience", "1")">1</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="setExperienceValue()">2</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="setExperienceValue()">3</a><br>
  ...
</table>
<select class="form-control  input-lg" id="experience"name="experience" 
  placeholder="Experience (in Years)" required="">
 <option value="">Experience: </option>
 <?php
              $sql="SELECT * FROM experience";
              $result=$conn->query($sql);
              if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo "<option value='".$row['value']."' data- 
              id='".$row['id']."'>".$row['value']."</option>";
                }
              }
            ?>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function setExperienceValue () {                            
          var element = document.getElementById(id);
          element.value = val;
            }

     </script>
```

I am trying to set the default value in the  listbox when the link in the table is clicked. How to populate the default value in such case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element) SO question,

Comment: @Jeroen Actually I am trying to set the default value from the selection in the table not any default value using "selected". Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by default value?

Comment: @Terminus By default value I mean if i select 1 in the table it should have the value 1 preselected in the drop down list.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you just want to click one of those `<a>` and that will change the value of the `<select>` without reloading the page?

Comment: You are absolutely right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy solution for the problem. By adding the option of data-select in the anchor tag and adding a javascript for on click function. Below is the code changes.

```
    <table>
    <td align="center">
    <a href="#exp" data-select="1">1</a><br>
  <a href="#exp" data-select="1"">2</a><br>
  <a href="#exp" data-select="1"">3</a><br>
  ...
</table>
<select class="form-control  input-lg" id="experience"name="experience" 
  placeholder="Experience (in Years)" required="">
 <option value="">Experience: </option>
 <?php
              $sql="SELECT * FROM experience";
              $result=$conn->query($sql);
              if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo "<option value='".$row['value']."' data- 
              id='".$row['id']."'>".$row['value']."</option>";
                }
              }
            ?>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">


    var $expe = $('#experience');
$('a[href="#exp"]').click(function () {
    $expe.val( $(this).data('select') );
});
         </script>
```

Hope this helps anyone facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So to make an `option` become default, you need to include `selected` attribute. You can easily do this and add a check with PHP to see if you want to include it. For example;

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $selected = null;
      if($row["selected"] === 1) { //or some other condition
         $selected= "selected";
      }
      echo "<option {$selected} value='".$row['value']."' data-id='".$row['id']."'>".$row['value'].</option>";
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I want the selected attribute to be active when I click on the <a> in <table> for the corresponding value. The above function only sets it as default directly not through the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not specify the element ID when calling document.getElementById(). If you are trying to get the id of the  for example, you need to use

   ```
   document.getElementById("experience");
   ```

You also need to specify some kind of an attribute to a to recognize it, example id="link".

Then:

```
var a = document.getElementById("link").textContent;
var selection = document.getElementById("experience");
selection.value = a;
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the information!! It is still not setting the value default when the anchor tag <a href="#" onclick="setExperienceValue("experience", "1")">1</a> is clicked.