# Design suggestion to choose a value as default in mutli select drop down

Tags: angularjs, html

In mutli select option, user had to choose one value as default.

Suggest me any UI design to achieve this.

Currently capturing the multiple value like below.But how to choose one as default among the three ?

[image]

Any HTML design or free libraries available.

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: From the selected three values(given in question) from multi select drop down , How can I give user a way to choose again one value as default from the already selected three.