# setting default-value in react select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to set a default value in my select tag so that on every onChange event I can call an API which is my requirement.

I searched online on how to set defaultvalue for select tag, people suggested to use defaultValue attribute which did not work for me.

```
    let serviceProviderLocationNames = this.props.serviceProviderLocationName.map((location, key) => {
        return <option key={key} value={location.SERVICE_PROVIDER_LOCATION_ID}>{location.DESCRIPTION}</option>
    });
```

```
<select
  defaultValue = {{ label: "Select", value: 0}}
  name="serviceProviderLocationDropDown"
  onChange={this.updateServiceProviderLocationId}
>
  {serviceProviderLocationNames}
</select>
```

I expected to see a "select" value as default and others to be the values that I got from an API, but I couldn't see the "select"

Comment: <select value = {{ label: "Select", value: 0}} name="serviceProviderLocationDropDown" onChange={this.updateServiceProviderLocationId}>{serviceProviderLocationNames}</select> This is how I am trying to render the dropdown on UI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `defaultValue` parameter.

```
 <Select
  name="form-dept-select"
  options={depts}
  defaultValue={{ label: "Select Dept", value: 0 }}
  onChange={e => {
              this.setState({
              department: e.label,
              deptId: e.value
              });
           }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To see `Select` by default, you need to add an `option` before your original `option` as,

```
<select
  value={this.state.selectedValue} //Add the selected value here, may be from state. For example `this.state.selectedValue` you can change the name whatever you have
  name="serviceProviderLocationDropDown"
  onChange={this.updateServiceProviderLocationId}
>
  <option>Select</option>   //By default selected
  {serviceProviderLocationNames}
</select>
```

`onChange` of your select you have `updateServiceProviderLocationId` function, and you might set selected value in `state`, you need to write that in `value` prop above so that it will become a `controlled` component.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w3giyz)

Comment: Adding an option tag worked for me. :-) Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to brush up  html element basics here. So to select value in dropdown by default you need to add selected to  html tag and that should take care of default selected item.

So you need to add login to select the element in the option and while change you should be able to get default value

```
let serviceProviderLocationNames = this.props.serviceProviderLocationName.map((location, key) => {
  return <option 
    key={key} 
    value={location.SERVICE_PROVIDER_LOCATION_ID} 
    selected={key=== PUT_INDEX_TO_BE_DEFAULT_SELECTED}
  >
    {location.DESCRIPTION}
  </option>
});
```