# How to dynamically set the default selected option in a Jinja template?

Tags: django, jinja2

I am building a dashboard which will have some information about users. I am trying to set value to select tag using Django but the value never get assigned. Here is my code.

My model look something like this

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name
    last_name
    reg_status
```

I need to fill in the template with the `reg_status`. The `reg_status` can contain three options, they are as mentioned below:

- `mailed`
- `register`
- `not register`

The value of `reg_status` is dynamic. For example, if I pass in `reg_status = mailed` from my view, I need the `<option value='mailed'>` to be selected. However, if I pass in the `reg_status = register` from my view, I need the `<option value='register'>` to be selected.

Here is how I am trying to render the content in the template:

```
{% for u in user %}
 <input type='text' value={{u.first_name}}/>
 <input type='text' value={{u.last_name}}/>
 <select value={{u.reg_status}>
  <option value='mailed'>mailed</option>
  <option value='register'>register</option>
  <option value='not register'>not register</option>
 </select>
{% endfor %}
```

The output give 'mailed' as selected for all instance even if the value is set to 'registered' or 'not registered'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: Nope its not a duplicate

Comment: Yes it is. You need to set the `selected` attribute on the <option> tag as the other question shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Jinja ternary operator. It's a little greedy because you're doing the same operation 3 times. You could also look into setting a global variable with Jinja (see the [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/), scroll down to *Scoping Behavior*).

```
<select value='{{ u.reg_status }}'>
  <option value='mailed' {{ "selected='selected'" if u.reg_status == 'mailed' else "" }}>mailed</option>
  <option value='register' {{ "selected='selected'" if u.reg_status == 'register' else "" }}>register</option>
  <option value='not register' {{ "selected='selected'" if u.reg_status == 'not register' else "" }}>not register</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: When you set selected='selected' for the first option it override the value which you pass under select tag

Comment: @skid Ah, I misunderstood what you were asking. Is the value of `u.reg_status` going to be one of `mailed`, `register`, or `not register`? If so, I might suggest updating your question to make that a bit clearer. I'll update my answer in just a sec

Comment: yes the value of u.reg_status will be either mailed,registered,not registerd i am trying to render the existing data from the database to my template inorder to make a dashboard kind of view.

Comment: @skid Updated my answer.