# emberjs: Passing selected value to select field in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am attempting to add a SELECT field from first principles using ember and am having difficulty working out how to pass the currently selected option to a form when editing a record.

I have set the form up as a component and am able to use it successfully when creating a new record, with the selected value being passed to the Rails backend.
My issue is that I cannot work out a way to apply this selected value to the form component when editing an existing record.

Here is the component template section (book-form.hbs):

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="format" onchange={{action 'updateValue' value='target.value'}}>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Paperback">Paperback</option>
      <option value="Hardcover">Hardcover</option>
      <option value="E-Book">E-Book</option>
    </select>
```

Template code (book-form.js):

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  actions: {
    submitChange(param) {
      this.onSave(param, this.selectedOpt);
    },
    selectedOpt: "",
    updateValue(value) {
      this.set('value', value);
      this.selectedOpt = value;
    },
  }
});
```

new & edit templates:

```
{{book-form onSave=(action 'saveBook') model=model}}
```

new controller:

```
export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    saveBook(newBook,format) {
      var tmp = this.store.createRecord('book', {
        title: newBook.title,
        author: newBook.author,
        genre: newBook.genre,
        format: format,
      });
      tmp.save();
      this.transitionToRoute('books.list');
    }
  }
});
```

edit controller:

```
  actions: {
    saveBook(book) {
      book.save();
      this.transitionToRoute('books.list');
    }
  }
```

I know I'm missing something somewhere to pass the model value through to the component but am not sure how to do it or where it belongs.

I would appreciate any assistance at all.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone looking at this question is using Ember Octane (3.14+)

This'd be what you want (based on @AhmetEmre's answer):

The Template:

```
<select id="format" {{on 'change' this.updateValue}}>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Paperback" selected={{eq this.value "Paperback"}} >Paperback</option>
  <option value="Hardcover" selected={{eq this.value "Hardcover"}} >Hardcover</option>
  <option value="E-Book" selected={{eq this.value "E-Book"}}>E-Book</option>
</select>
```

The JS for the component:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  @tracked value = 'Hardcover';

  @action updateValue(event) {
    this.value = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML select element's default value can be achieved by [using selected argument in option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518011/7399478).

So your template .hbs will be like:

```
<select id="format" onchange={{action 'updateValue'}}>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Paperback" selected={{eq value "Paperback"}} >Paperback</option>
  <option value="Hardcover" selected={{eq value "Hardcover"}} >Hardcover</option>
  <option value="E-Book" selected={{eq value "E-Book"}}>E-Book</option>
</select>
```

and your component.js will be like:

```
value: 'Hardcover', 

actions: {
  updateValue(event){
    this.set('value', event.target.value); 
  }
}
```

You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e11356c3f7e4763076ae98101bf3aabf) for example usage. By the way, this example depends on [ember-truth-helpers addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers) by using `eq` helper.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ahmet.
Unfortunately that made no difference at all.
The selected value is not being transferred through to the component when the record is entered.