# How can any dropdown list or checklist option selected by default on page load in html

Tags: html, validation

Suppose,
problem 1:
There's a cities drop-down list: 1) Lahore 2)Gujranwala 3)Islamabad
Requirement is that: Gujranwala Should selected by default when page is loaded
Problem 2:
There's a class checklist: 1) Non-Technical 2)Technical 3)Creative Design
Requirement is that: Technical should checked by default when page is loaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `selected="selected"` in the option that you want to be selected by default. For you example use this on Gujranwala.
and add `checked` in the input tag to make it checked by default.
**Check and run the code snippet**

```html
<select>
  <option> One </option>
  <option> two </option>
  <option> three </option>
  <option> four </option>
  <option selected="selected"> five </option>
</select>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" checked> Checked
<br>

<input type="checkbox" > Unchecked
```