# Setting the selected value of a dropdown option

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on a simple calculator app in Laravel Blade. We have not moved to models yet, just working in views and routes, so I keep running into options I haven't learned how to use yet.

My application is running without issue but is not retaining the selected value in the dropdown on POST. I am able to print the value to the screen, and it is working in a later selector.
I think I just need to write an if statement in the options to set the selected value, but I can't find syntax that I understand/am allowed to use in this project.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="operatorInput" name="operatorInput" value="{{Session::get('operator')}}">
        <option value="+" @if(Session::get('operatorInput') == "+" ? "selected" : "" )@endif>Addition (+)</option>
        <option value="-" @if(Session::get('operatorInput') == "-" ? "selected" : "" )@endif>Subtraction (-)</option>   
      </select>
    </div>
```

I get a throwable error on this example, so I know it isn't correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I want to set the selection and then pass it to POST so my dropdown displays the value selected until I clear it. Setting the default just makes that value the one that is held in session and is then posted. Thank you though!