# Set default value for select dropdown in Php

Tags: php, html

I'm a absolute newby for `php` and i'm struggling with just a basic thing.

I want to set a default value for a select box i have. Default value should be `2`

**My code**

```
        <div class="selector-wrapper">
                <select id="adults" class="form-control" onchange="toggleSetGuests()">
                <?php
                for($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++):
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if($i == 0){ echo('selected="true"'); }  ?>>
                    <?php echo $i ?> Adults
                </option>
                <?php
                endfor;
                ?>
                </select>
        </div>
```

So in this select box i get options from 0 - 20. I want to set the default value as `2` instead of `0`

My approach was like below

```
<option value="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if($i == 2){ echo('selected="true"'); }  ?>>
```

But did not work.

How do i set the default value to be selected as the value `2`

Comment: `selected="selected"` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: The example code is working just fine. Tested on PHP 5.6 - 7.4. Maybe it's some kind of issue with the surrounding HTML?

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if($i == 2){ echo ' selected'; }  ?>>
```

should work.You don't need `selected=true`