# Identify if select tag holds value due to selected attribute in options

Tags: javascript, html

In my understanding, a select value will set default value in 2 ways:

1. Check if "selected" attribute for any option
2. Else place first option as selected

```
<select name="gender">
  <option>Select Gender</option>
  <option value="1">Male</option>
  <option value="2">Female</option>
  <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way through which I can find out by which step(above mentioned) is the default value set for this select

Comment: Have a look at this maybe, it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: The presence of  `[default]` attribute on an `<option>` ex. `<option default>Select Gender</option>` the value in this case is `"Select Gender"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the options and check if there's a selected attribute.

```
const options = Array.from(document.querySelector('[name=gender]').children);
//If there isn't a selected attribute it will be undefined
options.forEach(c => {
    console.log(c,!!c.attributes.selected);
})
```

Note: Selecting from dropdown doesn't add the selected attribute so this code will be true even after user chooses an option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. Use css selectors to get the count of all option elements that are selected (and have a value). If the count is zero, choose the index of the one you want (in this example #2)

```js
let sel = document.querySelector('select[name="gender"]');
if (sel.querySelectorAll('option:checked[value]').length === 0) {
  sel.querySelectorAll('option')[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
}
```

```html
<select name="gender">
  <option>Select Gender</option>
  <option value="1">Male</option>
  <option value="2">Female</option>
  <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>
```