# How to make defaultValue work on select when options are generated dinamically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a select and the options for it are generated on a function, I'd like to set a value on the `defaultValue` and have the option with this value being selected by default, but it's not the way it's working right now. I have replicated the problem on this CodeSandbox: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wind-f9fcp?file=/src/App.js).

I'm also displaying the mock data on the screen so you can check which person it should be selecting. In the code, I set the default value to be `defaultValue={3}`, so the user with id "3" is the one I'd want to have selected.

This is the code for those who can't access the codesandbox:

```
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      let result = await getUsers();
      setUsers(
        result.map((r, index) => {
          let temp = r;
          temp["idd"] = index;
          return temp;
        })
      );
    };

    fetch();
  }, []);

  const generateOptions = () => {
    let aux = users.map((u, key) => {
      return (
        <option key={key} value={u.idd}>
          {u.name.first}
        </option>
      );
    });
  
    return aux;
  };

  const getUsers = async () => {
    let data = [];
    await axios
      .get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10", {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
      })
      .then((r) => {
        data = r.data.results;
      });
    return data;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {users ? (
        <>
          <div className="App">
            <select defaultValue={3}>{generateOptions()}</select>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div>loading...</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You can add the "selected" attribute to the option item, or use selectElement.value = [value of option to select]

Comment: You need to set it like this `<option selected="selected">`. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: @ControlAltDel adding attributes to the options won't work for me, the function that generates the options is supposed to be generic and work for all kind of items, so that I only have to change the defaultValue on the select element. About the selectElement.value, I guess that could work, but why doesnt it work with defaultValue?

Comment: @Samir in a way yes, but off the top of my head I can't think of how I can implement this ```generateOptions``` function in a way that it will work for different kind of objects using the attribute on the *option* element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be the select component needs to re-render. If you add a key of `users.length` to the `select` it forces it to re-render and work

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-lake-j9h1y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Still doesn't work, unless I'm messing something up

Comment: Updated the answer