# Selected attribute isn't working in InertiaJS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I looked everywhere to solve this one but I couldn't find any information about it. I have a normal select HTML tags with dynamic options and a form. All I need is to show the latest created category as the selected option by default so I'm passing the options from laravel with `orderByDesc` and I can see that when I click on the dropdown it shows the latest on top but it never show any value by default which means selected attribute isn't working.

`web.php`

```php
'categories' => auth()->user() ?
            category::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderByDesc('created_at')->get()
            : []
```

`frontend`

```php
<select
                        name="category_id"
                        id="category_id"
                        class="min-w-max text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent border-2 rounded-xl"
                        v-model="productForm.category_id"
                    >
                        <option
                            v-for="category in categories"
                            :key="category.id"
                            :value="category.id"
                            selected
                        >
                            {{ category.name }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

`the form`

```js
const productForm = useForm("createProduct", {
    category_id: null,
    categName: null,
    title: null,
    price: null,
    type: null,
    currency: null,
    desc: null,
    qty: null,
    thumbnail: null,
});
```

If there is a better approach to select menus with InertiaJS I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: You are setting the `selected` attribute on all instances of the `<option>` element. Change it to only the one you want to be selected, and it should work as intended. You can verify this by using the element inspector in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using Inertia.js, you can set the default value on the form itself. Since we're using v-model to pass the input value to the form, set the default value on the form itself.

```js
const productForm = useForm("createProduct", {
    category_id: 1,
});
```

This will set the selected value to '1' by default.