# How to select default value that should display the records in aura from the drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, aura.js

I have multiple fields on UI and i am getting the data based on the feilds so for the specific field() it has two values in the dropdown menu( yes and No). So whenever i open the UI I want the records saying yes automatically but it should allow me to select for no from the drop-down. Any idea how can i acheive this.

```
<td class="filterrow">

<lightning:select aura:id="status" name="Status" onchange="(!c.SubSearch)"

value="{!v.status)" variant="label-hidden">

<option value=""></option>

<option value="Yes">Yes</option>

<option value="No">No</option>

</lightning:select>

</td>
```

We have it in component along with the attribute
And subserach in controller with

```
Status= component. Get(v.Status)
```

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element?

Comment: This is to default select the value but i have some records associated with that value so i want both scenarios to be executed